# Como retornar o índice de uma MATRIZ em java

Tags: java, matriz

estou com um pequeno problema que acredito ser lógico mas não consigo resolver.

Vamos supor que, escrevi um pequeno algoritmo que cria 10 painéis e os coloca um ao lado do outro, como mostra abaixo.

```
JPanel painel[]= new JPanel[10];
for(i = 0; i < 10; I++)
{
    painel[i].setSize(10, 10);
    painel[i].setLocation(2 * i, 0);
    painel[i].setBackground(Color.black);
}
```

A dúvida entra agora, supondo que eu queira que estes mesmos painéis possam ser clicáveis *(a partir de agora, me corrijam se estiver algo errado)*, então eu adiciono mais uma parte dentro do loop, o que deixa o código assim:

```
JPanel painel[]= new JPanel[10];
for(i = 0; i < 10; I++)
{
    painel[i].setSize(10, 10);
    painel[i].setLocation(2 * i, 0);
    painel[i].setBackground(Color.black);
    painel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Agora surge o problema, a minha intenção é que quando algum dos painéis criados for clicado, ele deverá retornar o índice da matriz na qual ele está localizado, só que não sei como fazer isso dentro do método, muito menos se o que eu fiz até agora está certo, se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei eternamente grato.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "retornar" o índice quando o painel for clicado?

Comment: Imprimir o valor por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
        /*escrever o indice "i" aqui não funcionaria?
         uma ideia seria definir o nome das jpanes e escrevelas nesse evento de click.
        */
        }
```